# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no bridge2java in java.library.path

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, parallels

Can anyone write me how to deal with this error? I am running a project with eclipse (from 2012-2014) configured for Windows. I do it on a Mac but Parallels whit windows 11

What library to use and how to add it, if something else needs to be done ?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no bridge2java in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1738)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
at com.ibm.bridge2java.OleEnvironment.Initialize(OleEnvironment.java:10)
at tr.com.yurticikargo.kopsproject.client.YKEdsFrame.main(YKEdsFrame.java:41)
```